# Convert 12hour clock to 24hour clock PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

I would really love some help with this.

Currently when I use the following PHP, **my output is 02:42**.
What **I would like is 14:42**.

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); 

echo date("h:i",time()); 

?>
```

**Also**, is it possible to then use the converted time value to create a conditional statement to say **if greater than 10am, do this**.

Many thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of these:
G - 24 hour c (0-23)
H - 2 digit 24 hour (00-23)

```
echo date("H:i", time());
```

Also to check

```
$hour = date("H", time());

if($hour > 10)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at php documentation for more date formatting:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

Use `"H:i"` for 24h time.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Many thanks, Emyr. And how would I then use this value to determine if it's greater or less than 10am?

Comment: Using 24h time, any time string after 9:59 will be 5 chars long, before 10:00 will be 4 chars long. That's only a good way of doing it if you have the string anyway. If you don't need the string, just extract the hour part as a number and compare that with the number 10.

Answer (score 5):

you can accomplish that with:

```
date("H:i",time());
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo date("H:i",time());
```

Will give you 24-based hours.

For the second Problem you could use:

```
if(date("a") == "pm" OR date("g") > 10){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do is change the lower case **h** into an upper case **H**

all the formats you can use are here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: They were *very* fast. I think Emyr clinches it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
date("H:iA",time());
```

the A, will give you AM or PM

Comment: You don't need AM or PM in a 24 hour clock, it's kinda the point.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert to 24 hours clock to 12 hours clock

```
    $date='17:29';
    echo  date ('g:i a',strtotime($date));
    output: 5:29 pm
```

This will convert to 12 hours clock to 24 hours clock

```
    $date='5:29';
    echo date ('H:i',strtotime($date));
    output: 17:29
```